# Kotlin coroutines not running in parallel?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to use Kotlin coroutines to run 2 queries in parallel. I get the result as expected, but they are running sequentially.

```
fun getSearchResults(
    sql: SqlBuilder,
): Pair<Int?, List<T>> {
    return runBlocking {
        val one = async {
            count(sql)
        }
        val two = async {
            query(sql)
        }

        Pair(one.await(), two.await())
    }
}

suspend fun count(sql: SqlBuilder): Int? {
    return namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql.countSql, sql.params) { rs: ResultSet, _: Int ->
        rs.retrieveInteger("count")!!
    }
}

suspend fun query(sql: SqlBuilder): List<T> {
    return namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(sql.sql, sql.params) { rs: ResultSet, _: Int ->
        createEntity(rs)
    }
}
```

Why is this not running in parallel? Also, why is my IDE telling me the `suspend` keywords are "redundant"? How do I fix this?

Comment: You cant run in parallel because `runBlocking` is "block" a single thread (the current thread) and all coroutines inside this block are running in that thread

Answer (score 2):

When you launch a coroutine in `runBlocking`, the default dispatcher is a single-threaded dispatcher running in the thread that called `runBlocking`. You should not be using `runBlocking` anyway, since it defeats the purpose of using coroutines. Your `getSearchResults` function is a blocking function.

The reason `suspend` is redundant on your other functions is that those functions are not calling any other suspend functions. Aside from being redundant, the `suspend` keyword implies that the function will cooperate with cancellation and by convention does not block. Your implementation is breaking both of those rules because they do not call other suspend functions and they are calling blocking functions without wrapping them in `withContext` with an appropriate dispatcher, so they are themselves blocking functions. Blocking suspend functions must never exist by convention.

So the solution is to change `getSearchResults` to be a suspend function, and use `coroutineScope` instead of `runBlocking` in it so it will run its children coroutines in parallel and it will not block. If it is a suspend function, it won't be redundant for your other functions that call it to be marked `suspend`.

```
suspend fun getSearchResults(
    sql: SqlBuilder,
): Pair<Int?, List<T>> = coroutineScope {
    val one = async {
        count(sql)
    }
    val two = async {
        query(sql)
    }
    Pair(one.await(), two.await())
}
```

If `count` and `query` are blocking IO functions, you should use `async(Dispatchers.IO)` to call them. But if they are suspend functions you don't need to specify a dispatcher.

Comment: If a function that calls suspending functions should itself be marked as suspend, does that imply that the suspend marker would be propagated all the way up the call chain, right up to fun main, or should there be a runBlocking at some stage?

Comment: It’s propagated up the call chain to a launched coroutine somewhere. That can be a `launch`, `async`, or `runBlocking`, among others. Typically, `runBlocking` would only be seen at the top level `main` of a CLI app unless it’s a project that has a mixture of coroutines and some other thread management strategy.